# Bus Error Core Dumped given in terminal

Tags: 17.10, laravel, composer

i tried running the composer -v command and got the error - "Bus Error(core dumped)" in the terminal. Please is there any suggestion. Saw a place that said to run sudo apt update, tried that but it didn't work.Am on ubuntu 17.10. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install composer? There are (at least) two ways to install composer: using `apt install` or by downloading and running composer-setup.php.
Can you try to re-install it?

You can try

```
composer clear-cache
```

to clear the package cache and see if this solves your problem.
If not, you can rename the settings and global packages directory (on my system this is the ~/.config/composer directory). You'll lose all your settings and globally installed packages but you can always reinstall them or revert to the old directory.

Comment: i downloaded the composer-setup.php

Comment: tried re-installing it but it still give the same error

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**
Okay so this solved my problem.. I did a re-install of php after that i was able to re-install composer via sudo apt install composer then running the laravel new command began to work.. Thanks for your time